# Networkcallback called multiple times even after unregistering

Tags: android, android-connectivitymanager

In my android-app I need to call an API via my Wi-Fi connection which doesn't have an internet connection, even though cellular data is enabled. I manage to handle this with underneath code:

```
NetworkRequest.Builder builder;
builder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
builder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
builder.removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET);
final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
connectivityManager.requestNetwork(builder.build(), new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
       @Override
       public void onAvailable(Network network) {
             connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(this);

             SendAPIRequest();
       }
});
```

So far so good.
However, on certain android devices, the onAvailable method (and thus the SendAPIRequest method) is sometimes called multiple times, not always. As stated on developer.android.com, the networkcallback may be called more than once if the Network that is satisfying the request changes. (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback.html#onAvailable(android.net.Network))
But as you can see in my code, I unregister the networkcallback immediately to prevent this callback from being called another time, even if the Network changes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't see any problems with this. Are you sure `requestNetwork()` is not being called again after `unregisterNetworkCallback()`?

Comment: Yes, the posted code is nested in the onclickevent of a button. This button gets disabled as soon as it is clicked to prevent the code from executing multiple times.

Comment: Well, based on the [source code](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/net/ConnectivityManager.java), this basically can't happen. So, something else is going on that we're not seeing. I recommend you set a breakpoint on your call to `unregisterNetworkCallback()`, and verify that A.) Before the call, the `ConnectivityManager's` `sCallbacks` member contains a single entry (`NetworkCallback.this`), and B.) after the call, `sCallbacks` is empty. The question then is, if your breakpoint hits a second time, what's in 'sCallbacks'?

Comment: By the way, the version of `requestNetwork()` you used calls back to `onAvailable()` on a separate (background) thread. Are you aware of this, and did you handle it appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but for those who would be interested in this, I recently came across to notice that the callbacks are called from a worker thread. So there could be a race condition if you don't run your code on the main thread. Also onAvailable can still be called after unregistering the callback. So you will need to implement in a way that stuff you do inside of onAvailable is safe to be called even after its living context is gone.

e.g. Proves onAvailable runs on a worker thread

```
override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
                    Logging.i(Logging.APP_STATE, "Network available")
                    if (Thread.currentThread() != Looper.getMainLooper().thread) {
                        throw RuntimeException("What? This doesn't run on the main thread!")
                    }
                    isConnected = true
                }
```

Comment: I am getting android.net.ConnectivityManager$TooManyRequestsException:  during network operation can you please help me why this its same related what you answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75079780/android-net-connectivitymanagertoomanyrequestsexception-in-android-while-networ i have posted this question