# android.net.ConnectivityManager$TooManyRequestsException in android while network call

Tags: android, retrofit, android-connectivitymanager

```
  override fun setR2SettingData(cmd: String, status: String) {
        val requestbuilder = NetworkRequest.Builder()
        requestbuilder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
        connectivityManager.requestNetwork(
            requestbuilder.build(),
            object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
                    val builder1 = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    builder1.socketFactory(network.socketFactory)
                    val apiService =
                        RetrofitInstance.getApiServiceXMLForR2(
                            Constants.BASE_URL_CAMERA_R2,
                            builder1
                        )
                    trackDisposable(
                        apiService.requestCameraR2URLForSettingResponse(cmd, status)
                            .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
                            .observeOn(schedulerProvider.ui())
                            .subscribe()
                    )
                }
            })

    }
```

This code i am using network call when we call API some time I am recieving the following error:  `android.net.ConnectivityManager$TooManyRequestsException`

```
   Process: com.rovedashcam.android, PID: 25285
    android.net.ConnectivityManager$TooManyRequestsException
        at android.net.ConnectivityManager.convertServiceException(ConnectivityManager.java:3378)
        at android.net.ConnectivityManager.sendRequestForNetwork(ConnectivityManager.java:3564)
        at android.net.ConnectivityManager.requestNetwork(ConnectivityManager.java:3585)
        at android.net.ConnectivityManager.requestNetwork(ConnectivityManager.java:3661)
        at android.net.ConnectivityManager.requestNetwork(ConnectivityManager.java:3622)
        at 
   connectivityManager.requestNetwork
```

can anyone tell me why I am getting this error?

Comment: Where do you call this `setR2SettingData()` function?

Comment: @Zain Thanks for quick answer i am calling from view Model

Comment: Can you debug and log if it's called multiple times; you'd add a log message and see

Comment: @Zain i have already debug it its calling but its synchronously multiple times so is there any way to fix it ?

Comment: Just make sure that it's not triggered in lifecycle methods that got called multiple times such as onResume/onStart.

Comment: I am sure  its not getting call multiple time we are using mutableLive data to update view  of API Response .  I don't know why this happening while  all Api is running in background .

Comment: @MARSH found any solution on this?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried resolving this by integration `connectivityManager` with `fragment` lifecycle methods

Here is my implementation.

1. Create Class properties

   ```
   private var connectivityManager:ConnectivityManager? = null
   private val connectionCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {//perform your stuff}
        override fun onLost(network: Network) {//perform your stuff}
   }
   ```
2. Initialise and register `ConnectivityManager` in `onCreateView()`

   ```
   connectivityManager = requireContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
   connectivityManager?.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(connectionCallback)
   ```
3. `unregisterNetworkCallback` in `onPause()/onStop()/onDestroy()` based on your requirement

   ```
    connectivityManager?.unregisterNetworkCallback(connectionCallback)
   ```